# Getting TypeError on prerendering page in npm run build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am prerendering this page on my Next.js application:

```
const router = useRouter();

if (!router.isFallback && !postData?.slug) {
    return <p>hmm... looks like an error</p>
}

const formatDate = date => {
    const newDate = new Date(date);

    return `${newDate.getDate()}/${
        newDate.getMonth() + 1
    }/${newDate.getFullYear()}`
};


    return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
        <Head>
            <title>{postData.title}</title>
            <link rel='icon' href='/favicon.ico' />
        </Head>

        <main className={styles.main}>
            {router.isFallback ? (
                <h2>Loading...</h2>
            ) : (
                <article className={blogStyles.article}>
                    <div className={blogStyles.postmeta}>
                        <h1 className={styles.title}>{postData.title}</h1>
                        <p>{formatDate(postData.date)}</p>
                        <img src={postData.featuredImage.node.sourceUrl} />
                    </div>
                    <div
                        className='post-content content'
                        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: postData.content }}
                    />
                </article>
            )}
            <p>
                <Link href={`/blog`}>
                    <a>Back</a>
                </Link>
            </p>
        </main>
    </div>
)
```

Using `getStaticProps()`

```
    export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    const data = await getPost(params.slug);

    return {
      props: {
        postData: data.post
      }
    };
  }
```

Using `getStaticPaths()`

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const allPosts = await getAllPostsWithSlug();

    if (
        allPosts &&
        allPosts.edges !== null &&
        allPosts.edges.node !== null &&
        allPosts.edges.length > 0
    ) {
        return {
            paths: allPosts.edges.map(({ node }) => `/blog/${node.slug}`) || [],
            fallback: true
        }
    }

}
```

When I run it locally it works fine but when I try to deploy it with `npm run build` it gives an error just for the `title` property only:

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/blog/[slug]". Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

This is the part that confuses me as I don't understand why the error is only on 1 property (postData.title) of the query and everything else loads fine.

I am using GraphQL to create the query:

```
export async function getPost(slug) {
    const data = await fetchAPI(
      `
      fragment PostFields on Post {
        title
        excerpt
        slug
        date
        featuredImage {
          node {
            sourceUrl
          }
        }
      }
      query PostBySlug($id: ID!, $idType: PostIdType!) {
        post(id: $id, idType: $idType) {
          ...PostFields
          content
        }
      }
    `,
      {
        variables: {
          id: slug,
          idType: 'SLUG'
        }
      }
    );

    return data;
}
```

I import this function through an api.js file and use the data in the getStaticProps() function.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated, I looked for solutions online but couldn't find any that worked. Thanks!

Comment: can you show the whole page.js? is something like `function home ({postData}){}` ?

Comment: It only errors at `postData.title` because that's the first property you try to access from `postData` in that page, it doesn't get to the others after erroring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When handling a dynamic page such as `/blog/[slug].jsx` you need to use `getStaticPaths` in addition to `getStaticProps` and `router.isFallback?` as you're using in the returned jsx above.

[`getStaticPaths` catches incoming possible paths](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#the-fallback-key-required) -- its behavior however is dependent on a `fallback` key (which can have the values `true`, `false`, or `"blocking"`)

`Blocking` is identical to Server Side Rendering so it generates static HTML on demand for paths not returned by `getStaticPaths`. This is cached for future use so that this on demand generation only happens once per path not handled by your `getStaticPaths` function. If you set `getStaticPaths` to `true` then a small subset of dynamic paths will be rendered at build time and a loading indicator will be displayed to the user if a path they navigate to isn't rendered during the initial build. Using `true` is useful for large e-commerce sites or sites with a large number of dynamic paths so that the build process doesn't take a ridiculously long time to complete. Setting `getStaticPaths` to `false` will result in any path not rendered during the build process to result in a 404 error if a user navigates to it. Depending on your needs, any of the above methods could be most appropriate. That said, it is important to note that `"blocking"` does not require the use of `router.isFallback` at all. I also suggest looking into the benefits of utilizing `revalidate` with `getStaticProps`.

Here is an example of using `getStaticPaths` to catch incoming dynamic paths:

```
const AboutSlugsQueryVars: AboutSlugsVariables = {
    order: OrderEnum.ASC,
    field: PostObjectsConnectionOrderbyEnum.SLUG,
    first: 15
};

type DynamicPaths = {
    params:
        | {
                slug: string | Array<string>;
          }
        | never[];
}[];

export async function getStaticPaths(
    ctx: GetStaticPathsContext,
    pathsData: DynamicPaths
) {
    const q = ctx!.defaultLocale;
    console.log(`${q}`)
    const apolloClient = initializeApollo();
    const { data } = await apolloClient.query<AboutSlugs, AboutSlugsVariables>({
        query: ABOUT_SLUGS,
        variables: AboutSlugsQueryVars
    });

    pathsData = [];

    if (
        data &&
        data.aboutslugs !== null &&
        data.aboutslugs.edges !== null &&
        data.aboutslugs.edges.length > 0
    )
        data.aboutslugs.edges.map(post => {
            if (post !== null && post.node !== null && post.node.slug !== null) {
                pathsData.push({ params: { slug: post.node.slug } });
            }
        });

    return {
        paths: pathsData,
        fallback: true
    };
}
```

There are many approaches to filtering `getStaticPaths`, you can also use `GetStaticPathsContext` to catch incoming `locales` as well as the default `locale` (if applicable).

Comment: I have already used fallback and getStaticPaths().  I should have attached the code. I updated my question. It's only for one of the fields I'm getting this error which perplexes me. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is hitting this or similar issues with `yarn export`, the solution is to set the fallback to false. This fixed all page rendering errors for me.

From the Next.js docs:

```
// This function gets called at build time
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  // Call an external API endpoint to get posts
  const res = await fetch('https://.../posts')
  const posts = await res.json()

  // Get the paths we want to pre-render based on posts
  const paths = posts.map((post) => ({
    params: { id: post.id },
  }))

  // We'll pre-render only these paths at build time.
  // { fallback: false } means other routes should 404.
  return { paths, fallback: false }
}
```